# TSQL Extracting code and description from a column

Tags: t-sql

I need to extract code and description from a column, which looks like below:

```
USERTEXT1,Investment type Investor Type   ,AD~Advisory FOF~Fund of Funds SP~Structured Product FE~Feeder EX~Exclude CDV~CD Vehicle USERTEXT2,Investment type Advisory Capacity   ,ND~Non Discretionary DI~Discretionary USERTEXT3,Investment type CD Input   ,WI~with involvement NI~no involvement USERTEXT4,Investment type Investment Type CD   ,PRIM~Primary SEC~Secondary GP~GP USERTEXT5, Current or Realised Investment   ,C~Current R~Realised USERTEXT6,Identity UNIQUE ID   , USERTEXT7,Client specific PICA Acc. Method   ,COST~Cost EQ~Equity USERBOOL1,Investment type Default Investor?   , USERDATE1,Investment type Default Date   , USERTEXT8,Client specific Naming Convention   , USERTEXT9,Client specific Property Number   ,
```

The output I expect would be:

```
Field Code Description
USERTEXT1 AD Advisory
USERTEXT1 FOF Fund of Funds
USERTEXT1 SP Structured Product
(...)
USERTEXT2 ND Non Discretionary
USERTEXT2 DI Discretionary
(...)
USERTEXT6 NULL NULL
```

I'm interested only in USERTEXTxx fields, and as you can see not all of them have values.
I am fighting with function and different loops, but cannot get the correct output :/
I would really appreciate your help.

Below is my function i have created so far, but maybe there is some other, quicker, better solution. And my fuction doesn't work in 100%

```
Create function dbo.rad_AdditionalField(@table varchar(50), @field_name varchar(50), @code varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

-- select dbo.rad_additionalfield('vcsubscriber', 'usertext1','FOF')
--Declare @table varchar(50) = 'VCSUBSCRIBER'
Declare @add_field varchar(max) 
--Declare @field_name varchar(50) = 'USERTEXT1'
--Declare @code varchar(10) = 'FOF'

Declare @individual varchar(4000) = NULL
Declare @int int = 0
Declare @field varchar(100)
Declare @descr varchar(200)
Declare @value varchar(max)

Declare @tab table(field varchar(100), descr varchar(200), value varchar(max))

select @add_field = USERTYPES1 
from ADMTABLE
where CLASS1=@table


WHILE LEN(@add_field) > 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('%USER%',@add_field) > 0
    BEGIN
        set @int=@int+1
        SET @individual = SUBSTRING(@add_field, 0, PATINDEX('%USER%',@add_field))
        if @int > 1 
        BEGIN
            SELECT @field=Data from dbo.rad_split('U' + @individual,',') where ID = 1
            SELECT @descr=Data from dbo.rad_split('U' + @individual,',') where ID = 2
            SELECT @value=Data from dbo.rad_split('U' + @individual,',') where ID = 3

            insert into @tab(field, descr, value)
            values(@field, @descr, @value)


        END

        SET @add_field = SUBSTRING(@add_field, LEN(@individual + ',') + 1,
                                                     LEN(@add_field))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = @add_field
        SET @add_field = NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @field=Data from dbo.rad_split('U' + @individual,',') where ID = 1
            SELECT @descr=Data from dbo.rad_split('U' + @individual,',') where ID = 2
            SELECT @value=Data from dbo.rad_split('U' + @individual,',') where ID = 3

            insert into @tab(field, descr, value)
            values(@field, @descr, @value)
        END
        --SELECT * from dbo.rad_split('U' + @individual,',')
    END
END
declare @tylda varchar(max)

Select @tylda = value from @tab where field = @field_name
--select @tylda
--select * from rad_split(@tylda,'~')


Declare @products varchar(4000) = @tylda
Declare @individual2 varchar(200) = null
Declare @sep varchar(20) = @code + '~'
DECLARE @ret_value varchar(100)

WHILE LEN(@products) > 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('%'+@sep+'%',@products) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @individual2 = SUBSTRING(@products, 0, PATINDEX('%'+@sep+'%',@products))
        -- SELECT @individual2

        SET @products = SUBSTRING(@products, LEN(@individual2 + @sep) + 1,
                                                     LEN(@products))

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @individual2 = @products
        SET @products = NULL
        if CHARINDEX('~',@individual2) > 0 select @ret_value = ltrim(rtrim(left(@individual2,CHARINDEX('~',@individual2) - LEN(@sep)-1)))
        else select @ret_value = ltrim(rtrim(@individual2))
    END
END
    RETURN(@ret_value)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. split the long string by deliminator (,)
 2. each row that contain ~ split by deliminator ( )
 and store in a #table you name it 'USERTEXT(x)'
 3. do not store string with '%user%'

this is not exactly what you looking for but very close



AD~Advisory FOF~Fund of Funds SP~Structured Product FE~Feeder EX~Exclude CDV~CD Vehicle USERTEXT2
Investment type Advisory Capacity   
ND~Non Discretionary DI~Discretionary USERTEXT3
Investment type CD Input   
WI~with involvement NI~no involvement USERTEXT4
Investment type Investment Type CD   
PRIM~Primary SEC~Secondary GP~GP USERTEXT5
```

Comment: if you need i can post split func

Comment: Thank you for your help but you can have more than one USERTEXT(x) fields in the column (as in the example in the original post), how would you know that these codes and description belongs to this USERTEXT(X) field?

Comment: look at the edited answer you willsee one usertext per row.you can search for a number and it will be your (x).-againt it is no exactly what you need .you will have to adjust it

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that I cannot easily find which USERTEXT(x) belongs to which codes and descriptions. If you runn the split function on the whole string you will get something like:
(...)
 USERTEXT7
Client specific PICA Acc. Method   
COST~Cost EQ~Equity USERBOOL1
Investment type Default Investor?   
(...)
Now I need to link USERTEXT7 to COST Cost | EQ Equity

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to extract your data.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Test TABLE (value1 NVARCHAR(100), value2 NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Test VALUES
    ('data1','data2'),
    (NULL,'data2'),
    ('data1','data2'),
    (NULL,NULL),
    ('data61',NULL),
    ('data31','data21'),
    ('data19','data20')

DECLARE @Data NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Data = ''

SELECT @Data = @Data +
    COALESCE(value1,'NULL') + ' ' +
    COALESCE(value2,'NULL') +CHAR(10)
FROM @Test
--Where x = y
--and z > 3

PRINT @Data
```

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it is not solution to my problem, to be honest i'm not even sure what your code is supposed to do. My problem is that from the column (the long line) i need to extract code and description.

Comment: Alright i looked at what you really wanted and the solution to it is follow the patterns so far so good but there is a problem, the pattern in this line is broken for example `FOF~Fund of Funds`, here you cant know when the next column is going to begin.. unlike here `AD~Advisory` the next column is going to begin after the blank space.

Answer (score 0):

after subtraction of all kind of ,'Investment .....,'  you will have this string

```
USERTEXT1,
AD~Advisory FOF~Fund of Funds SP~Structured Product FE~Feeder EX~Exclude CDV~CD Vehicle 
USERTEXT2,
ND~Non Discretionary DI~Discretionary 
USERTEXT3,
WI~with involvement NI~no involvement 
USERTEXT4,
PRIM~Primary SEC~Secondary GP~GP 
USERTEXT5,
Current or Realised Investment   ,C~Current R~Realised 
USERTEXT6,
Identity U 
Client specific PICA Acc. Method   ,COST~Cost EQ~Equity USERBOOL1,
USERDATE1,
USERTEXT8,
Client specific Naming Convention   ,
USERTEXT9,
Client specific Property Number
```

from here you will need a lot of imagination

how to extract usertext(x) and linked to it the appropriate field...

Comment: I was looking for the help with linking the field to the codes and descriptions, there is no problem with spliting the column (as you can see in the function from the original post). Thank you for you time.